# The program has unexpectedly finished. try catch throw in Qt

Tags: qt, throw

I have a problem in my qt project, when an exception is thrown my windows crash and close, why? Where is the problem? I do not understand.

```
   class MyException:public std::exception{
    private:
        QMessageBox* mex;
    public:
        MyException(QString);

    };

    class err_parser_binary:public MyException{
    public:
        err_parser_binary(QString);
    };

MyException::MyException(QString d):mex(new QMessageBox()){
    mex->setText("Error");
    mex->setDetailedText(d);
    mex->button(QMessageBox::Ok);
    mex->show();
}

err_parser_binary::err_parser_binary(QString detail): MyException(detail){

}

QString binary_controller::calcolaop1op2(QString x, QString y, QString op) try{
...............
    Binary* pb=new Binary(op2);

..................
}
catch (err_parser_binary) {}

Binary::Binary(std::string str){
......
        throw err_parser_binary("only 1 o 0");
......
}
```

Comment: error: The program has unexpectedly finished.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've read, Qt is not really exception safe. Take a look at [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/exceptionsafety.html) page. At the top, it says:

> **Preliminary warning**: Exception safety is not feature complete! Common
>   cases should work, but classes might still leak or even crash.
>
> Qt itself will not throw exceptions. Instead, error codes are used. In
>   addition, some classes have user visible error messages, for example
>   QIODevice::errorString() or QSqlQuery::lastError(). This has
>   historical and practical reasons - turning on exceptions can increase
>   the library size by over 20%.

You should just use error codes and/or error messages instead.

Comment: Eh, just saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130734/exception-safety-in-qt after I posted this.